# ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue returning nothing even though there is a key for the value I am retrieving

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, binding

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project.

I have implemented a custom IModelBinder class.In the BindModel method I am attempting to retrieve the ID (a GUID) of an item like this:

```
Public Class MyViewModelModelBinder
    Implements IModelBinder

    Public Function BindModel(controllerContext As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, bindingContext As System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext) As Object Implements System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder.BindModel

         Dim myVM As MyViewModel
         If (bindingContext.Model IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf bindingContext.Model Is MyViewModel) Then
            myVM = DirectCast(bindingContext.Model, MyViewModel)
         Else
            myVM = New MyViewModel
         End If 

         Dim proposedObjectID As Guid = GetValue(Of Guid)(bindingContext, "ObjectID")
         myVM.ObjectID = proposedObjectID
         '...'
         Return myVM
    End Function
    Private Function GetValue(Of T)(ByVal bindingContext As ModelBindingContext, ByVal key As String) As T
        Dim returnValue As T = Nothing
        Dim valueResult As ValueProviderResult
        valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key)
        If valueResult IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                returnValue = DirectCast(valueResult.ConvertTo(GetType(T)), T)
            Catch ex As Exception
                returnValue = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
        Return returnValue
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem that I am having is in the `GetValue` method because the `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key)` method is returning `null`/`nothing`. One would assume that would be because the key and/or the value isn't in the `ValueProvider` but that is not the case...The `ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue` is returning null/nothing even though there is a key and a value for the item that I am trying to retrieve.

I can retrieve the ID by doing the following:

```
 Public Function BindModel(controllerContext As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, bindingContext As System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext) As Object Implements System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder.BindModel
         Dim proposedObjectID As Guid 
         Guid.TryParse(CType(bindingContext.ValueProvider, FormCollection)("ObjectID"), proposedObjectID)
        '...'
 End Function
```

But I am having a hard time understanding why the `GetValue` method isn't retrieving the value properly.

Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I found my problem. I had accidentally added a space in the end of the key that I was providing to the `GetValue` method. OOPS! *Blush*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

I had accidentally added a space to the end of the key that I was providing to the `GetValue` method. So, the key (with the appended space) actually didn't exist in my collection!